# Apache Camel netty udp consumer not working without a decoder

Tags: apache-camel, netty

If I have following camel route and send udp message, nothing gets printed to stdout:

```
    <route>
        <from uri="netty:udp://0.0.0.0:5000"/>
        <to uri="mock:stdout"/>
    </route>
```

However if I add a decoder I can see the udp message bring printed on stdout

```
<bean class="org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder" id="stringDecoder">
    <constructor-arg value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="netty:udp://0.0.0.0:5000?decoder=#stringDecoder"/>
        <to uri="mock:stdout"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Can someone plz explain me why the default decoder does not pass the message to mocked endpoint. Is it waiting for a EOF kind of signal?

I am sending message using:

```
$ cat json.txt | nc -4u -w1 hostname 5000
```

Apache [camel netty](http://camel.apache.org/netty.html) page explains that:

```
allowDefaultCodec == true
Camel 2.4: The netty component installs a default codec if both,
encoder/deocder is null and textline is false. 
Setting allowDefaultCodec to false prevents the netty component from installing a 
default codec as the first element in the filter chain.
```

Comment: Did you try setting `textline` to true? If false, it will try to use object serialization on the message.

Comment: Camel documentation says that textline is "Only used for TCP". I am doing UDP.

Answer (score 0):

The string decoder requires you to use a new line to terminate the string. So make sure to include that when you send.

eg in the javadoc and code example you can see they use `\n`
https://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/string/StringDecoder.html

Comment: Thx Claus for coming back on this question. I am sending json message in the udp packet and then later using jackson decoding the json string into proper json node objects. So there are many \n in the payload already.